# JSF How to redirect to another page determined at runtime with Command Button?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to call a method of a Bean and then, redirect the user to another page that is determined at runtime when this method is called and derived by some runtime calculations:
For example:

on the .xhtml:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userAuth.parameterA}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Save Changes" 
                 id="withIcon" 
                 type="submit"
                 actionListener="#{userAuth.saveChanges()}" 
                 icon="ui-icon-disk" />
```

on the bean:

```
public String saveGhanges(){
    this.entity.save(); //dummy code)
    if (this.parameterA == true) return "ATrue.xhtml";
    if (this.parameterA == false) return "AFalse.xhtml";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userAuth.parameterA}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Save Changes" 
                 id="withIcon" 
                 type="submit"
                 action="#{userAuth.saveChanges()}" 
                 icon="ui-icon-disk" ajax="false"/>
```

actionListener should be for void methods. i hope it helps.

Comment: It helped, thank you!
I thought action is called before rendering tha page

Answer (score 2):

Just like @pamps said, try replacing `actionListener` with `action` in your `commandButton`

`actionListeners` have `void` return type, while `actions` may have `void` or `String` as their return type!

Hope this helps!